# Calculating the angle between the line joining two points and the x-axis

Tags: programming, trigonometry

I need to calculate the angle between two points, the returned result should between $0$ to $2π$ and `getAngle[point1, point2]==getAngle[point2, point1]`.

I have tried this

```
ClearAll[getAngle];
getAngle[A : {x1_, y1_}, B : {x2_, y2_}] :=
  Module[{th},
   th = ArcTan[x2 - x1, y2 - y1];
   If[th < 0, th += Pi];
   th
   ];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line@p}, Axes -> 1, PlotRange -> 5, 
  PlotLabel -> getAngle @@ N@p],
 {{p, {{1, 1}, {3, 4}} // Reverse}, Locator}]
```

`getAngle[{1, 1}, {-2, -3}]` expected `π+ArcTan[4/3]`,returns `ArcTan[4/3]`

How to rewrite my function?

Comment: Psst, `VectorAngle[]` is built-in...

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a fairly simple mistake: when correcting the angle you add `Pi` instead of `2Pi`. However, I figured I'd make this an answer, because there's a much simpler way to handle this. You can use `Mod` to map the angles into the $[0, 2\pi)$ range. You can also compute the arctangent by applying `ArcTan` directly to the difference of the points so you don't have to fiddle with the individual coordinates:

```
getAngle[p1_, p2_] := Mod[ArcTan @@ (p2 - p1), 2 Pi]
```